# WooCommerce add quantity button to shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I would like to know how can I add a simple quantity button to my WooCommerce shop products.

[image]

Comment: Refer this link https://docs.woothemes.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/

Comment: what is simple quantity button to you?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i modified my loop/add-to-cart.php to achieve this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Loop Add to Cart
     *
     * @author      WooThemes
     * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
     * @version     1.6.4
     */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

    global $product;
    ?>

    <?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

        <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php
            $link = array(
                'url'   => '',
                'label' => '',
                'class' => ''
            );

            $handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $product->product_type, $product );

            switch ( $handler ) {
                case "variable" :
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) );
                break;
                case "grouped" :
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
                break;
                case "external" :
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
                break;
                default :
                    if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                        $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                        $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                        $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
                    } else {
                        $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                        $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
                    }
                break;
            }
            if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) {

                ?>
                <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                    <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>

                    <button type="submit" class="button alt"><?php echo $label; ?></button>

                </form>
                <?php

            } else {
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $link['url'] ), esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_attr( $product->product_type ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) ), $product, $link );
            }
        ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That worked great and also adds up right. Just wondering where do we edit the css for these buttons? As my add to cart button got squished and the quantity button is way to big. Thanks again life saver!

http://puu.sh/nxLAY/efe2ec4bb7.jpg